# Jenkins continually builds on Windows slave even with no repository changes

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a two Jenkins jobs tied to a particular Windows slave that build continually. They are set to poll the Git SCM with a cron expression of `* * * * *` but will build every minute even if there have been no changes in the Git repo. In the Git polling log for both jobs I see the following:

```
Started on 20-Jan-2012 10:57:10
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Build : #4179
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision 581837483fc583126d8fde7760c88062d3aa2cfa (origin/HEAD, origin/master)
Last build was not on tied node, forcing rebuild.
Done. Took 8 ms
Changes found
```

In particular the line saying `Last build was not on tied node, forcing rebuild.` seems suspicious. I can see a few reports of similar things when Googling this term but no solutions.

Other Windows slaves do not seem to be having the same problem so I'm not sure that it's purely a Windows issue.

Does anyone have any idea what might cause this or what I can do to resolve it?

Comment: Is it possible that the specific slave has a different time than the machine that holds the GIT repository? I've seen problems like this occurring with a SVN repository due to the fact that the slave and the repository machine were slightly out of sync (by about 2 mins or so). I'm not sure if GIT is susceptible to the out-of-sync problem but it could be worth checking.

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sure that the job has been tied to a slave?

As a solution to a similar looking issue with the message "Last build was not on tied node, forcing rebuild", tying the job to a slave node has been suggested: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=334069

Comment: Yes, it's definitely tied to a slave

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've just solved this one for our build server (running Hudson) with the help of:
http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/OkDctYWEcMGCgTIDY2Av

> When you tie a job to a slave configuration, in the configuration file 
>   following is written

```
<assignedNode>hudson-slave1</assignedNode>
```

> When a build finishes, a file is created

```
<job>/builds/<build-no>/build.xml.
```

> This file has

```
<builtOn>hudson-slave1</builtOn>
```

> I noticed one odd thing. If you see the label I printed out above it 
>   says "hudson-slave1" which belongs to the node "hudson-slave1". 
>   Strangely, the node "hudson-slave1" has two labels "build2" and 
>   "hudson-slave2". There is no such label "hudson-slave1" (see the first 
>   picture).**

In our case build was tied to a node "BUILDDEV3" which had its label as "major-builders".

I added the node name to the list of labels (by changing the labels list to "major-builders BUILDDEV3") and immediately it started behaving.

It seems that the node name is being compared to the labels to determine if the last build was on the tied node.

This is probably a bug that has been missed because, I'm assuming, if you tie to a label, then it will work as then label will be compared to label.

So, in summary, add the node name to the list of labels and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this issue with Hudson v2.2.1 (yeah, I know its an ancient version). I am not sure what triggered the runaway builds, as no configuration changes seem to align with the start of the runaway. I have, however found an (additional) work-around.

On the job config page, there is an option (checkbox) for "Restrict where this project can be run", with two (radio-button) options to select the means of restriction: "Node and label menu" or "Advanced Node and Label expressions", one of which must be selected.

When the second of those options, "Advanced Node and Label expressions", is selected, a free-form text field appears that allows you to enter a logical expression that combines terms from

- the set of slave node names ("BUILDDEV3" in @Campey's answer), **union**
- the set of of all slave label values ("major-builders" in @Campey's answer).

For example, `major-builders && !BUILDDEV3`.

When the first of those options, "Node and label menu", is selected, a selection list appears that allows you to pick one value from a list that contains terms from:

- the set of slave node names, **union**
- the list of all slave label values, **union**
- the set of all expressions currently defined in any job from the "Advanced Node and Label expressions" mechanism.

Notice, that the set of slave node names are inherently treated as slave labels. @Campey's suggestion is to not mess with the selection mechanism, but to explicitly add the slave node name to the list of labels for each slave. This will work, but has potential side effects, say, if you rename a node. I haven't tried it but it may even cause duplicates to show in the list of selection terms for the dispatch selector. I prefer to avoid redundant information capture.

My work-around is to not ever select the implicit slave node names, but only use labels or expressions containing only labels in the selection mechanism, regardless or which one you pick. This will never be redundant.

For example, to express the example given earlier: `major-builders && !BUILDDEV3`, where "major-builders" is a label and "BUILDDEV3" is a node name, one would have to add a unique node label to the node "BUILDDEV3" such as "NOTHERE", and then use the expression, `major-builders && !NOTHERE`.